# Count distinct number of CampaignId where array contains specific value in mongodb collection

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

> My document structure:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58a55f1a1f19ce1c0c436418"),
    "Status" : false,
    "Headers" : [ 
        "Campaign Name", 
        "Ad Set Name", 
        "Ad Name", 
        "URL Tags", 
        "Bid Amount", 
        "Ad Set Daily Budget", 
        "Campaign Status", 
        "Ad Set Run Status", 
        "Ad Status", 
        "Campaign Objective", 
        "Buying Type", 
        "Ad Set Time Start", 
        "Use Accelerated Delivery", 
        "Link Object ID", 
        "Optimized Conversion Tracking Pixels", 
        "Optimized Event", 
        "Countries", 
        "Location Types", 
        "Gender", 
        "Age Min", 
        "Age Max", 
        "Custom Audiences", 
        "Excluded Custom Audiences", 
        "Flexible Inclusions", 
        "Targeting Optimization", 
        "Publisher Platforms", 
        "Facebook Positions", 
        "Device Platforms", 
        "Automatically Set Bid", 
        "Use Average Bid", 
        "Optimization Goal", 
        "Optimization Conversion Window (Days)", 
        "Billing Event", 
        "Story ID", 
        "Conversion Tracking Pixels", 
        "Creative Type", 
        "Instagram Account ID"
    ],
    "CampaignId" : "Promoted | Kristin Filomena 2 | S:1176609245738008 | 02-14-2017 | 69",
    "AdSetId" : 100.0,
    "AdId" : "ACTIVE",
    "Values" : [ 
        "Remarketing | Facebook | Conversions | 02-14-2017", 
        "Cancelled Orders_Greater than 50%-Cancelled Orders_Less than 50% | Desktop | Feed | Female | 21-65", 
        "Promoted | Kristin Filomena 2 | S:1176609245738008 | 02-14-2017 | 69", 
        "utm_source=Facebook&utm_medium=social&utm_campaign=Remarketing | Facebook | Conversions | 02-14-2017&utm_term=Cancelled Orders_Greater than 50%-Cancelled Orders_Less than 50% | Desktop | Feed | Female | 21-65&utm_content=Promoted | Kristin Filomena 2 | S:1176609245738008 | 02-14-2017 | 69", 
        "100", 
        "50", 
        "PAUSED", 
        "ACTIVE", 
        "ACTIVE", 
        "Conversions", 
        "AUCTION", 
        "02/14/2017 19:02", 
        "No", 
        "o:147003252031951", 
        "tp:274128649620874", 
        "ADD_PAYMENT_INFO", 
        "US", 
        "home", 
        "Female", 
        "21", 
        "65", 
        "23842531891940746:Cancelled Orders_Greater than 50%, 23842531892040746:Cancelled Orders_Less than 50%", 
        "23842531887430746:Current Customers_All, 23842531979690746:Complete Registration - Last180Days", 
        "", 
        "none", 
        "Facebook", 
        "Feed", 
        "Desktop", 
        "No", 
        "No", 
        "OFFSITE_CONVERSIONS", 
        "1", 
        "IMPRESSIONS", 
        "s:1176609245738008", 
        "tp:274128649620874", 
        "Link Page Post Ad", 
        ""
    ]
}
```

> I have 288 documents with similar structure in my mongodb collection.
>   I need to get the distinct count of field campaignId in which "Values" array contains
>   "Remarketing | Facebook | Conversions | 02-14-2017" value(it could be
>   any element of Values array, right now i am considering the first
>   one).
>
> What i have done so far is,

```
db.adsets.aggregate([
                        {$match:{Values:"Lookalike | Facebook | Conversions | 02-14-2017"}},
                        {$project:{_id:0,Values: 1}},
                        {$unwind:"$Values"},
                        {$group:{_id:"$Values",count:{$sum:1}}},
                        {$project:{_id:0,Values:1,count:1}}
                    ]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this. This will give you the count of documents where you have at least one element matching criteria in `Values` array.

```
db.collection.count({Values:"Lookalike | Facebook | Conversions | 02-14-2017"}})
```

Update:

```
db.collection.distinct("CampaignId", {Values:"Lookalike | Facebook | Conversions | 02-14-2017"}).length;
```

Comment: Sorry i wrote my title wrong, i need to count the distinct number of campaignid

Comment: No problem. Updated answer. See if it works for you.

Comment: Thanks, you are awesome. I have no idea what i was trying to do earlier. You made it look so easy.

Comment: Can you tell me an alternative if i don't have CampaignId field separately. I mean if i include this field inside values array and i sill want to perform the same operation?

Comment: I think that is a separate question. Please feel free to create a question and someone will be happy to answer you.

Comment: Sure. Thanks alot.